# I concat string in Java and compared that with itself, equals return false. Why?

Tags: java

I've run the following code:

```
 String s1 = "Hello";
 if(s1.equals(s1.concat(" World"))) 
 System.out.println("true");
 else
 System.out.println("false");
```

The output is "false". Why s1 is not equals to itself?

Comment: What makes you think you are comparing it to itself?

Comment: I thought concat method edits the string, so after concat is called s1="Hello world". Now I've understood how method works

Comment: Strings are immutable so concat() will return a new String which is not equal to `s1`

Answer (score 5):

`s1` is equal to itself.

`s1.concat(" World")` does not modify `s1` but returns a new String object which is not equal to `s1`.

Answer (score 1):

Java strings are immutable. When you do `s1.concat(" World")` you create a new string with the contents "Hello World". The original "Hello" string is not modified.

You can see this example in action:

```
String hello = "Hello";
hello.concat(" World"); // Does not modifiy hello.
System.out.println(hello);  // Will print "Hello".
```

You must store the modified string if you want the new value:

```
String hello = "Hello";
hello = hello.concat(" World");
System.out.println(hello);  // Will print "Hello World".
```

Answer (score 0):

Because what are you comparing it's `Hello World` if it's equals with `Hello`. So your program it's right.

With `s1.concat(" World")` you are getting the String `Hello World` and `.equals()` function let you know if two Strings are exactly equals each other.

Answer (score 0):

The output is false because you aren't comparing s1 to itself. In fact, you're comparing s1 which contains the value "Hello" to the updated s1 which contains the value "Hello World". That's why it evaluates to false. Also, next time, if you have to perform such an operation, use this code. It serves the same purpose but is much more efficient.

```
System.out.println(s1.equals(s1.concat(" World")));
```